# Streaming HTTP body over FTP with twisted

Tags: python, python-2.7, ftp, streaming, twisted

I have a custom FTP server which talks to an api for folder listings etc, and the files come back as urls from the api. I'm trying to open a http stream to these urls and feed the data back through ftp the client (in a non blocking way) but I can't figure out how to hook it up.

I've tried to put together a minimal example to better explain my issue. In the example it starts a local FTP server on port 2121 which lists the local file system, but when downloading a file it returns the content body of www.yahoo.com instead of the file data.

I tried buffering the data through a `io.BytesIO` object, but no data is sent across. I'm wondering if this is the right approach or if it's because the read pointer is always at the end of the file object perhaps?

Here's the example code:

```
import io
from twisted.python import log
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol
from twisted.web.client import Agent, ContentDecoderAgent, GzipDecoder
from twisted.protocols.ftp import FTPFactory, FTPRealm, FTPAnonymousShell, _FileReader
from twisted.cred.portal import Portal
from twisted.cred.checkers import AllowAnonymousAccess, FilePasswordDB
from twisted.internet import defer

agent = ContentDecoderAgent(Agent(reactor), [('gzip', GzipDecoder)])

class StreamWriter(Protocol):
    def __init__(self, finished, stream):
        self.finished = finished
        self.stream = stream

    def dataReceived(self, bytes):
        self.stream.write(bytes)

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print 'Finished receiving body:', reason.type, reason.value
        self.finished.callback(None)


def streamBody(response, stream):
    finished = Deferred()
    response.deliverBody(StreamWriter(finished, stream))
    return finished

def openForReading(self, path):
    d = agent.request("GET", "http://www.yahoo.com")

    stream = io.BytesIO()
    d.addCallback(lambda resp: streamBody(resp, stream))
    d.addErrback(log.err)

    return defer.succeed(_FileReader(stream))

def main():

    FTPAnonymousShell.openForReading = openForReading

    p = Portal(FTPRealm('./'), [AllowAnonymousAccess()])

    f = FTPFactory(p)

    reactor.listenTCP(2121, f)
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

**Edit**

```
class FinishNotifier(ProtocolToConsumerAdapter, Protocol):
    def __init__(self, original):
        ProtocolToConsumerAdapter.__init__(self, original)
        self.finished = defer.Deferred()

    def connectionLost(self, reason=connectionDone):
        reason.trap(ConnectionDone, ResponseDone)
        self.finished.callback(None)

class HTTP2FTP(object):
    def __init__(self, response):
        self.response = response

    def send(self, consumer):
        protocol = FinishNotifier(consumer)
        self.response.deliverBody(protocol)
        return protocol.finished

def openForReading(self, path):
    d = agent.request("GET", "http://www.yahoo.com")

    d.addCallback(HTTP2FTP)
    d.addErrback(log.err)

    return d
```

updated runnable example:

```
from twisted.python import log
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, ConsumerToProtocolAdapter, connectionDone
from twisted.web.client import Agent, ContentDecoderAgent, GzipDecoder, HTTPConnectionPool, HTTPClientFactory
from twisted.protocols.ftp import FTPFactory, FTPRealm, FTPAnonymousShell
from twisted.cred.portal import Portal
from twisted.cred.checkers import AllowAnonymousAccess
from twisted.internet import defer
from twisted.internet.error import ConnectionDone
from twisted.web._newclient import ResponseDone

agent = ContentDecoderAgent(Agent(reactor), [('gzip', GzipDecoder)])
# pool= HTTPConnectionPool(reactor,persistent=True)
# pool.maxPersistentPerHost = 2
# agent= Agent(reactor,pool=pool,connectTimeout=5)

class FinishNotifier(ConsumerToProtocolAdapter):
    def __init__(self, original):
        ConsumerToProtocolAdapter.__init__(self, original)
        self.finished = defer.Deferred()

    def connectionLost(self, reason=connectionDone):
        reason.trap(ConnectionDone, ResponseDone)
        print "finished"
        self.finished.callback(None)

class HTTP2FTP(object):
    def __init__(self, response):
        self.response = response

    def send(self, consumer):
        print consumer
        protocol = FinishNotifier(consumer)
        self.response.deliverBody(protocol)
        return protocol.finished

def openForReading(self, path):
    d = agent.request("GET", "http://www.testtest.com")
    d.addCallback(HTTP2FTP)
    d.addErrback(log.err)

    return d

def main():

    FTPAnonymousShell.openForReading = openForReading

    p = Portal(FTPRealm('./'), [AllowAnonymousAccess()])

    f = FTPFactory(p)

    reactor.listenTCP(2121, f)
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if it's because the read pointer is always at the end of the file object perhaps?

Probably this.  You have two things going on simultaneously.  The HTTP client is writing to the `BytesIO` instance and the FTP client is reading from it.  `_FileReader` (a private API, an implementation detail of Twisted's FTP library, not something you should actually be using) is for reading from a file that's complete already - not a file that's growing *as* it's being read from.

Fortunately there's no need to go through the asynchronous-unfriendly `file` interface.  Look at the type that `openForReading` is supposed to return - an `IReadFile` provider.  `IReadFile` has one method, `send`, which accepts an object that provides `IConsumer`.

On the other side, you have `deliverBody` which accepts an `IProtocol`.  This protocol has the HTTP response body delivered to it.  This is the data you want to give to the `IConsumer` passed to `IReadFile.send`.

So instead of trying to make these two pieces work together with a `BytesIO`, make them work together using the two interfaces involved: `IProtocol` and `IConsumer`.  Here's a sketch (plenty of bugs in it but the general shape is correct):

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import ConsumerToProtocolAdapter
from twisted.internet.interfaces import IPushProducer
from twisted.protocols.ftp import IReadFile

class FinishNotifier(ConsumerToProtocolAdapter):
    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        reason.trap(ConnectionDone)
        self.finished.callback(None)

@implementer(IReadFile, IPushProducer)
class HTTP2FTP(object):
    def send(self, consumer):
        protocol = FinishNotifier(consumer)
        response.deliverBody(protocol)
        # Lazy hack.
        # This code probably belongs in protocol.connectionMade instead.
        self._producer = protocol.transport
        consumer.registerProducer(self._producer, streaming=True)
        protocol.finished.addCallback(
            lambda ignored: consumer.unregisterProducer()
        )
        return protocol.finished

    def pauseProducing(self):
        self._producer.pauseProducing()

    def resumeProducing(self):
        self._producer.resumeProducing()

    def stopProducing(self):
        self._producer.stopProducing()
```

Note that by implementing `IPushProducer` here, we get flow control between the HTTP and FTP connections (so that memory usage on the server will be bounded, even if the HTTP connection transfers data much more quickly than the FTP connection).  That's a pretty cool thing and it's nice that it's only a handful of extra lines to implement.  The slightly less cool thing is that you *must* make the `unregisterProducer` call at the right time.  The FTP protocol implementation uses this as indication that the data has been completely transferred.  This is probably not quite documented sufficiently in Twisted (and that's an oversight that should be corrected).

Comment: Great thanks @Jean-Paul. I think I was getting hung up on trying to return a `_FileReader` which needed a file like object. Your answer makes a lot of sense. I still can't seem to get it working quite- i get empty files returned and I can't work out why, I'll edit my question with what I tried

Comment: Just edited the question with an updated runnable example, can't work out why I'm still not getting any data across- it looks as if it should be working to me. Where I add HTTP2FTP, does that need to return a deferred at that point?

Comment: When I run the example, justdevelop.it replies with an HTTP/1.0 response without a content-length.  So `connectionLost` is called with `PotentialDataLoss` so the transfer is never recognized as done (because `connectionLost` doesn't handle that exception type).

Comment: Ah- I changed the URL. I guess I could add `PotentialDataLoss` to the trap or add a url that returns a content length sorry!

Comment: The urls I'll be using to get files down using the API will all have a content length so I needn't worry about that

Comment: It appears to get stuck in a "transferring" state, with no data being sent. Any ideas on how I could debug this? I'm not sure what's going on exactly

Comment: Oops.  Okay, half the problem is my answer is wrong - I said ProtocolToConsumerAdapter but I should have said ConsumerToProtocolAdapter.  Fix that and you'll get data being transferred.  It still doesn't ever finish the transfer though, I'm not sure what's causing that yet.

Comment: Ah thanks for taking another look! I've switched the class to `ConsumerToProtocolAdapter` but I can't seem to get it to transfer data even, it seems to behave the same for me still. I've edited the question again which what I have now

Comment: When I run the code in your question, I do get data transferred.  It gets to the `print "finished"` line and then the FTP server sends "226 Transfer Complete.".  But the FTP client I'm using doesn't seem to notice or care and seems to continue to wait for more data.

Comment: Hm using FileZilla I see the 226 Transfer Complete, no `print "finished"`, the file it creates is empty and it is sat in a "transferring" state, presumably waiting for data.

Comment: That `HTTP2FTP.send` method seems to sometimes get a DTP object, and sometimes a ASCIIConsumerWrapper and I can't quite work out why there's different objects coming through or what the differences relate too. I noticed adding `getattr(self.original, "stopProducing", lambda: None)()` (only DTP has stopProducing) makes it work some of the time, but still hangs other times.

Comment: This rather hideous line inside `connectionLost` appears to fix the issue- but I suspect it's not the actual solution and more of a sticking plaster. Would you say this is a solution? `(getattr(self.original, "stopProducing", None) or getattr(self.original, "unregisterProducer", lambda: None))()`

Comment: The difference between `ASCIIConsumerWrapper` and the `DTP` is due to the FTP file transfer mode - binary or ascii.  This will probably depend on automatic detection in your FTP client based on filename.  I think calling `stopProducing` is definitely a hack that only works by accident.  In that case, what you're essentially doing is explicitly closing the DTP connection.  Aha.  But now I see that calling `unregisterProducer` is probably the right thing to do (which probably means you should also call `registerProducer` at some point).  This is what `FileSender` does.

Comment: It seems like it's probably a bug that you *have* to unregister a producer in order to finish the data transfer - or else it's a bug in the documentation that this isn't made clear (worth filing against Twisted if you're up for it).  Probably this was overlooked because `FTPAnonymousShell.openForReading` / `_FileSender` does this and most people just use those with their FTP server rather than implement something custom.

Comment: I've updated the answer to have a rough sketch of how producers should be involved in this answer.  Apart from fixing the bug we've been discussing, this also improves the quality of the resulting implementation: there is now flow control between the HTTP and FTP connections.  If the FTP client falls behind the HTTP client, the HTTP client will pause until the FTP client catches up (so memory usage on the server is bounded).  When I initially answered I thought this extra stuff would be an optional part but I guess it's actually sorta mandatory.

Comment: That's fantastic!! Thank you JP! I'd upvote a few more times if I could! I made a couple of small changes to your example but it is working perfectly. I also can't find IFileSender, only FileSender. I'll try and put a bug report on twisted in the next few days.

Comment: Actually what is `protocol.transport`? Do I need to save that attribute in the `madeConnection` method in `FinishNotifier`?

Comment: Hmm I meant something else when I wrote `IFileSender`... what was it... Ah right, the FTP interface, `IReadFile`.  Sorry about that.  `protocol.transport` in this case is the transport that gets supplied to you by the HTTP client.  It's sort of like a normal transport except you can't write to it (because an HTTP client can only read the HTTP response, it's not allowed to send more data).  You need it in order to do the flow control - it's the thing you tell to slow down or speed up depending on how well the FTP connection is keeping up.

Comment: So just to clarify because `FinishNotifier` doesn't seem to have a `transport` attribute, should it be created from the object passed in in `__init__` or `makeConnection`? Sorry for all the questions!

Comment: My expectation is that `response.deliverBody(protocol)` will cause the `FinishNotifier` instance's `makeConnection` to be called with a suitable transport object.  That's the transport object you want (it's the one supplied by the HTTP client).  You can't create it yourself (because it belongs to the HTTP client and is associated with the HTTP client's connection), you have to wait for it to be passed to `makeConnection`.

Comment: Ah ok thanks, I guess I need to overwrite `makeConnection` then and store the reference. Thanks! I'll give that a go.